# NodeJS get Google Sheet list

Tags: node.js, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a list (dropdown, or data validation - list from ranges, as Google Sheets call it), like so:

[Image of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQlvC.png)

Imagine that in the list I have 4 values to select from. **My goal** is not only to get all table values, but also all values that constitute the list ["Beer","Wine","Rum","Martini"].

I've tried 2 different ways to retrieve the info and the list:

a) With **sheets.spreadsheets.values.get**, I get the table values in a digestible way, but not the content of the dropdown. Instead, the cell comes in as blank ("") [Comment: on Apps Script, you would get this information]

b) With **sheets.spreadsheets.getByDataFilter**, I get much more than I need and in a horrible format. However, I do not get the dropdown content as an array (as I'd want), but rather as a refence: (userEnteredValue: "=Input!$F$5:$F$7")

The question is, how do I get only the table, including the dropdown content as an array? I know it is possible and easy to do in Google Apps Script (I have it implemented), but not on Node.

Below the code as a reference for other programmers.

```
var {google} = require("googleapis");
let privatekey = require("./client_secret.json");

// configure a JWT auth client
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    ]);

//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected!");
    }
});

//Google Sheets API
let spreadsheetId = '<SPREADSHEET ID>';
let sheetName = 'Input!A1:B4'
let sheets = google.sheets('v4');

exports.fetch = (req, res) => {

    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: sheetName,
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        } else {
            res.json(response);
        }
    });  
    
    // OR

    sheets.spreadsheets.getByDataFilter({
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        "includeGridData": true,
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        } else {
            res.json(response);
        }
    });  

}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about `get only the table, including the list content as an array`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, @Tanaike! I edited the topic (underneath the table) and tried to clarify further. Pls let me know if clearer now? But basically I want all content, also inside the list

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your updated question, unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your current issue and your goal. 1. What is `[List]` im the table? 2. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the sample input values? And also, can you provide the sample output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand about your question.

Comment: I also do not udnerstand what you mean by list. Do you mean a dropdown menu? Can you provide a screenshot of the cell content?

Comment: Thanks everyone - 2 didn't understand, so clearly this is on me. I put a picture to explain better. Yes, it is a dropdown. Sheets call it a "List from Range", and it's in the data validation tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What you are interested in is dataValidation

In order to retrieve it, you can use the method [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get), setting the parameter `fields` to `sheets/data/rowData/values/dataValidation`

- If your data validation is set as `List of items`, the response will look like:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "dataValidation": {
                    "condition": {
                      "type": "ONE_OF_LIST",
                      "values": [
                        {
                          "userEnteredValue": "Beer"
                        },
                        {
                          "userEnteredValue": "Wine"
                        },
                        {
                          "userEnteredValue": "Martini"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "showCustomUi": true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

- If your data validation is set as `List form a range` the response will look like:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                {
                  "dataValidation": {
                    "condition": {
                      "type": "ONE_OF_RANGE",
                      "values": [
                        {
                          "userEnteredValue": "=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "showCustomUi": true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the latter case you would need to call subsequently the method [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) on `=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3` - that is the range returned as `userEnteredValue` within the object `values` nested within the object `dataValidation`.

Comment: Thanks ziganotschka. It sucks though that Google doesn't support in its API the same kinds of objects they do in Script. You gotta bend over backwards to get simple info. But well, it is what it is.

Comment: Apps Script has more methods,however mind that the APIs are usually faster - even if potentially less intuitive to use in the beginning.